# Trouble getting A4988 to work with NEMA 17 motor - can't get the current sufficiently low with trimmer, also moves erratically

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm trying to setup an A4988 with a NEMA 17 motor. I've consulted numerous tutorials, and I'm pretty sure I've connected everything correctly.

The motor is a [Joy-IT NEMA 17-04](https://joy-it.net/en/products/NEMA17-04) with a rated voltage of 3.3 V and a rated current of 1.5 A.

The A4988 is a [Okystar OKY3902](https://www.okystar.com/product-item/a4988-driver-module-stepper-motor-oky3902/) with a [datasheet](https://okystar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/OKY3902.pdf) that I personally find a little too brief.

I'm controlling the A4988 from an Arduino Nano, and powering the A4988 from a 12 VDC 6 A power supply.

Problems:

1. One way of setting the trimmer I've seen is to continuously measure the potential difference between the trimmer and GND, and it should be a fairly low value. Sources differ, but whichever method I use, I get somewhere in the 0.7-0.8 V range. Originally, I trimmed it to around 0.8 V. Another way of trimming is to measure the coil current, which is consistently around 2 A, which is too high. But no matter the trimmer setting, I can't get it any lower. How many turns do one of these things go? For now, I've reverted back to the voltage measuring method, and set it around 0.6 V.
2. When powering on the 12 V power supply, the heat sink on the small chip gets REAL hot REALLY fast, and the motor really does strange things. I consider [this tutorial](https://lastminuteengineers.com/a4988-stepper-motor-driver-arduino-tutorial/) high-quality, and the example Arduino programs seems reasonable, but the motor just moves sort of erratically.

I've made a [small movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oojBVnJt8yw) where you can see the motor move.

I tried switching the motor with another one - same problem.

I tried switching the A4988 with another one - same problem.

EDIT: Schematic of the circuit: [image: Schematic showing how the A4988 is connected to the Arduino Nano]

EDIT: The Arduino Nano is connected to, and therefore powered from, my laptop computer via USB.

Comment: "How many turns do one of these things go?" - that particular one is a "single-turn" trimmer with maybe 280° of rotation from min to max.

Comment: Please show us a schematic of you you have it connected - particularly the power supplies.

Comment: 12V power to a 3.3V motor?  Motor phase resistance is 2.2Ω, so at 12V that would be max of 5.45A...

Comment: @brhans Yeah, I found out. Still works, though - I can still adjust the reference voltage. And I've added the schematic.

Comment: @rdtsc I was under the impression that a bipolar motor like a typical NEMA 17 would need a lot more voltage - 8-35 VDC - than the "rated" voltage. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I did try to drive it with 3.3 V at first, but absolutely nothing happened.

Comment: Does the OKY3902 include pull-up resistors on RESET and SLEEP?  If not, tie those to +5V with a 1k resistor.  What is going on with the ENABLE pin?

Comment: @rdtsc Pull-up resistors aren't mentioned in the datasheet, but I believe it would be unfair to label it an A4988 if it hadn't. The ENABLE pin is not connected, as none of the tutorials mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You should see and use this [datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J450/a4988_DMOS_microstepping_driver_with_translator.pdf).
Note that the minimum voltage for this circuit is 8V ...

EDIT: Are you sure that **MSx** (light pull-down) pins are "wired" to +5V through a resistor or grounded? Are RESET_ , Enabled_ connected?

> Enable Input (Enable_ ). This input turns on or off all of the
> FET outputs. When set to a **logic high**, the outputs are **disabled**.
> When set to a **logic low**, **the internal control enables the outputs
> as required**. The translator inputs STEP, DIR, and MSx, as well as
> the internal sequencing logic, all remain active, independent of the
> Enabled_ input state.

Here also something that can help you: Arduino shield is "nano" socket.
https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Use-the-CNC-V4-Board-despite-Its-quirks/
[image]

Comment: Precisely - that's why I'm using 12 VDC for the motor.

Comment: You need to recheck the specifications and your wiring, you have no 5V power to the nano. The 5V on the A4988 is for its VCC, not an output for another device. this is directly from the link you supplied: "The A4988 actually requires two power supply connections." There are other connections that change how the board works, you do not show them.

Comment: Sorry, not shown in the diagram is that the Nano is connected to my laptop via USB. It has power.

Comment: Originally, neither ENABLED nor any of the MSx pins were connected, because none of the tutorials I consulted mentioned them, but I've now connected them to GND, with no change. RESET is connected to SLEEP, because all tutorials mention that they should be.

Comment: After reading the fine datasheet, you provided (thank you!) I've not pulled both RESET and SLEEP high - still no change.

Comment: See this for 3D printer ... center schematic : https://reprap.org/mediawiki/images/3/3f/Arduinomegapololushieldschematic.png

Comment: RESET low then high (or tied to nano reset) ... **Enable low** ! Enables are, at starting, driven high. Then arduino program drives these pins LOW for enabling A4988 ... and stepper motor. https://www.my-home-fab.de/en/documentations/reprap-firmware/installing-marlin-firmware-on-ramps-1.4

Comment: I've connected RESET and SLEEP to +5V from the Arduino and ENABLE to Arduino GND. Still no change.

Comment: I used "grbl" driver software with this board without any problem. https://www.joom.com/fr/products/5f59f391d13e490106fb5d6f and with simple software of my own on this one https://www.reprap.me/arduino-cnc-shield-v4-expansion-board-for-arduino-engraver-3d-printer.html where there was a little error, if I remember well ...